# April Patch Tuesday broke RDP text boxes

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

After April patch tuesday, RDP works fine with radio boxes, checkboxes, listboxes, but text boxes do not work.  Haven't ruled out whether it is the virtual keyboard on the client end or something on the server end.  The mfc patch this week affects rdp clients.  Anybody already figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Appears that after rebooting the server, text box functionality came back. A little surprising because the problem did not show until the TabletPCs were rebooted after patches applied.  But at this point, the servers did not have their patches applied.